# Can't import from absolute paths using Typescript and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, path

I've tried many things to solve this issue. I'm trying to import from absolute paths defined on my `tsconfig.json`

on a file on my project I'm trying to use `import { UserModel } from "model/User";`

And on my `tsconfig.json` I have

```
{
....
"baseUrl": "src", 
"paths": {
  "model/*": ["model/*"]`
  }
....
}
```

I've tried changing the baseUrl to `"."`, `"./"` and changing the paths as well, but I'm always getting the same error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'model/User'
```

I have also tried to add an `index.ts` file to the `model` folder and export models from there, but still.. same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a package, then probably you are reserved to using the `ttypescript` lib + `@zerollup/ts-transform-paths` plugin - those will do the job. Also, building your package will have to use `ttsc` instead of `tsc`.

If, on the other hand, you are using a bundler to bundle your code together (like `webpack`), you will have to reserve to the ways provided by the bunder's config.

Also, if you are using ESLint, you'll have to make sure it uses `tsconfig.json` via `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` npm package.

Also, if you are using Jest for unit-tests, you will have to enumerate the possible "roots" like this:

```
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for your answer. I installed the plugin and I got 4 vulnerabilities, 2 being of high importance. Don't you know of another way maybe?

Comment: Hey hey! Well, this one should be server-only build-time tool, so I actually did not dig into that "vulnerability" topic. Back in a day it was the simplest way for me to make it work, and I still keep using this approach.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the help man, appreciate it.